# fragment remove/add issue searchview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview

I'm having some issues with a `searchView` in my `Fragments`.

So, when I'm pressing the `search_icon` within the `actionbar`, the method `searchClick()` is executed.

**menu_main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:onClick="searchClick"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10;


import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnCloseListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
{




   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       Intent sIntent = getIntent();
       if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(sIntent.getAction())) {
           String query = sIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

       }




   }
    public void searchClick(MenuItem item){
        Fragment frag = new Results();
        Fragment rem = new FaecherFrag();
        FragmentTransaction ft  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.remove(rem).add(R.id.FragFaecher,frag).commit();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);




        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        Fragment frag = new Results();
        Fragment rem = new FaecherFrag();
        FragmentTransaction ft  = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(rem).add(R.id.results,frag).commit();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        if (query.isEmpty()){return false;}else
        {t.setText(query);}

        return false;
   }
}
```

`searchClick` then removes the current `Fragment`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
tools:context="formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground">


   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/FragFaecher"
       android:name="formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10.FaecherFrag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           />




</RelativeLayout>
```

**FaecherFrag.Java**

```
package formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;


public class FaecherFrag extends ListFragment {
    sql sqlo = new sql();


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] m_fach = sqlo.getFaecher(getContext());


        ListAdapter adptFach =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(
                        getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_fach);
        setListAdapter(adptFach);
        //Array m_fach wird als Liste angezeigt
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        transFach(position);
        //uebergibt die Position des Fachs an die naechste Methode
    }
    private void transFach(int position){

        String[] m_fach = sqlo.getFaecher(getContext());
        String sql_fach = m_fach[position]; //String für die SQL-Abfrage. Zeigt welches Fach ausgewaehlt wurde
        String[] m_thema = sqlo.getThemen(getContext(), sql_fach);


        Intent toThemen = new Intent(getActivity(),Themen.class);
        toThemen.putExtra("thema_key",m_thema);
        startActivity(toThemen);

    }




}
```

and adds another `Fragment` that displays the query in a `TextView`

**fragment_results.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Results.Java**

```
package formelhelfer5_10.formelhelfer5_10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Results extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

My first Issue is, that when I submit the query, the second `Fragment` (`fragment_results`) "disappears" and the normal `ListFragment` (`activity_main`) appears. I don't know how to solve this.
The second Issue is, that when I dismiss/close the `Search Widget`, I expect the `OnCloseListener` to remove the second `Fragment` (`fragment_results`) and show the `ListFragment` (`activity_main`). Although I implemented this in the `OnCloseListener`, nothing happens. Or am I confusing the `OnCloseListener` with something else?

I would be glad, if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For first problem, you are setting onClick in xml for menu item. This is wrong and will not call. Please implement onItemMenuSelected using https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu